# New Activity throwing a NullPointerException

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception, android-activity

How do I simply display another xml file? I have created a new activity call `about.java` to do that but it crashed with a `NullPointerException`. Here's my main class calling `about.class`:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            Log.d("**MYLOG**", "Refresh clicked .. ");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case 2:
            //setContentView(R.layout.about);
            Log.d("**MYLOG**", "About clicked .. ");
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, About.class);
            this.startActivity(intent2);
            return true;
```

Here is my about.class

```
public class About extends Activity {

public About() {
     Log.d("**MYLOG**", "Inside About.java ..");
     setContentView(R.layout.about);

}
}
```

and my about.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="About page"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>
```

Here is my log:

```
12-26 14:28:43.560: D/**MYLOG**(1141): Inside About.java ..
12-26 14:28:43.560: D/AndroidRuntime(1141): Shutting down VM
12-26 14:28:43.560: W/dalvikvm(1141): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{wia.home/wia.home.About}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 14:28:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
```

Comment: Have you defined the about activity in you manifest file? This is a mistake I happens often to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that the log does not specify the line at which the NullPointerException was thrown. What I can see in your code though, is that you are expected to call setContentView in onCreate, not in the constructor. Try that and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Always set the content view for an `Activity` in the `onCreate` callback:

```
public class About extends Activity {

     public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
        super.onCreate(saved);
         Log.d("**MYLOG**", "Inside About.java ..");
         setContentView(R.layout.about);
     }
}
```

You shouldn't try to use the constructor of the `Activity`, initialize the `Activity` starting with the `onCreate` method, as the `Context` is valid from this callback forward.

Comment: i get "Return type for the method is missing" for "onCreate(Bundle saved)"

Comment: @user1930170 The return type is `void`. Check my answer.

Comment: thanks. after i added tat void i wasnt still getting anything displayed. i found that my xml file wasn't correct. i created a new one and it worked fine. thanks a lot for all your help